# Is there away to use the colour dialogue with a pen while making a visual basics paint?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

'I watched a youtube video that thought me how to make a paint software. It 'did great for the most part, but it taught me how to add only one colour per 'size, and i want to learn how to use a colour dialog with the size this is a 'link.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hj5pGZRuP_0)
'i tried dim adcolour as new pen(Brush)

```
    'This is Colour blue for example and for other colours that i manually added in
   Dim penBlS As New Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2)
   Dim penBl As New Pen(Brushes.Blue, 5)

        Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b)
            Static coord As New Point
    '       If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And tool = "pencil" Then
                g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    each button on the software sets colour to the string set
                If colour = "blue" And size = "2" Then
                    penBlS.StartCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
                    penBlS.EndCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
                    g.DrawLine(penBlS, coord.X, coord.Y, e.X, e.Y)
                ElseIf Colour = "blue" And size = "5" Then
                    penBl.StartCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
                   penBl.EndCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round

               Else
                   If size = "2" Then
                       penS.StartCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
                        penS.EndCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
                       g.DrawLine(penS, coord.X, coord.Y, e.X, e.Y)
                    ElseIf size = "5" Then
                        pen.StartCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
                       pen.EndCap = Drawing2D.LineCap.Round
                        g.DrawLine(pen, coord.X, coord.Y, e.X, e.Y)
                    End If
                End If            
               g.Dispose()
                PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = b
                Me.Refresh()
    end if
    coord = e.location
    endsub
```

'I would Like to get the colour dialog colours for size 2 and 5

Comment: Your question is too broad and has very poor formatting. Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You add a colourdialog to your Form and a new button colourdialog and a new variable myColor to store the colour of the colourdialog

```
Private myColor As Color = Color.Black
Private Sub colourdialog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles colourdialog.Click
    myColor = If(ColorDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK, ColorDialog1.Color, myColor)
End Sub
```

Den you can define in your PictureBox1_MouseMove

```
Dim newp As New Pen(myColoren)
```

and use that instead of PenS or penBlS

Comment: is there a way I could send you my whole code, because I'm so lost as of now :(

Comment: Scrap your project start new. Make a mackup ofthe project, so that you can stqart over again  without going all the steps. Also it is a godd idea to set Option Strict  On. Then you have a chance to find problems ealy on.